# Python formatting integer (fixed digits before/after the decimal point)

Tags: python, string-formatting

I was wondering if it's possible to use two format options together when formatting integers.

I know I can use the bellow to include zero places

```
varInt = 12

print(
    "Integer : " +
    "{:03d}".format(varInt)
)
```

To get the output "Integer : 012"

I can use the following to include decimal places

```
varInt = 12

print(
    "Integer : " +
    "{:.3f}".format(varInt)
)
```

To get the output "Integer : 12.000"

But is it possible to use them both together to get the output "Integer : 012.000"

Comment: You can try with [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) also  `"{:.3f}".format(12).zfill(7)`

Comment: @BhargavRao, doesn't work for negative numbers

Comment: @JohnLaRooy  `"{:.3f}".format(-1).zfill(7)` prints  `'-01.000'`. Anyway thanks for the info. (Good that I did not add it as an answer) 
`

Comment: I do wonder why you didn't just use "{:03d}.000", since the fractional part of an _integer_ is the constant string ".000" by definition.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
varInt = 12

print(
    "Integer : " +
    "{:07.3f}".format(varInt)
)
```

Outputs:

```
Integer : 012.000
```

---

The 7 is **total** field width and includes the decimal point.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, the number at the beginning is the minimum length of the outputted string, so include the decimal part and the decimal point as well.

```
>>> "{:07.3f}".format(12)
'012.000'
```

Answer (score 5):

Not only can you specify the *minimum* length and decimal points like this:

```
"{:07.3f}".format(12)
```

You can even supply them as parameters like this:

```
"{:0{}.{}f}".format(12, 7, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who came here to format numbers in f string:

```
>>> a = 12
>>> f"{a:07.3f}"
'012.000'
```