# How do I convert 62 seconds into string 01 mins 02 secs

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
seconds = 62

print(seconds % 60, "secs")

print("%02d" % 2)
```

I cannot think of a way to get the one minute
I want the output as => `01 mins 02 secs`

Comment: You need to divide - `62 // 60 = 1`

Comment: Quite a few options for how to do this are only a Google search away. "Python convert seconds to hours minutes seconds"

Comment: `print(seconds / 60, " mins ", seconds % 60, " secs")` ?

Comment: I need double digits

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013276/python-integer-formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Python f-strings.

```
print(f'{int(seconds / 60):02} mins {int(seconds % 60):02} seconds')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    minute = int(62 / 60)
    seconds = 62 % 60
    print('%02d minute'% minute, end=' ')
    print('%02d secs'% seconds)
```

The output will be 1 minute 2 secs.

Comment: Also show the output of code and describe will make more clear your concept.